# How do I get an animal out of a boat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm on Minecraft transporting a cow by boat and this is kinda stupid of me but I have no idea how to get the cow out of the boat can anyone help?

Answer (score 24):

The only way to get the cow out of the boat is by destroying the boat.

Comment: But if you are beneath the boat when hitting it, you get the boat back in your inventory, so it isn't truely "destroyed". Boats are cheap anyway though.

Comment: This [wiki article](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Boat) talks about the behavior of mobs in boats. Apparently, destroying the boat is (still yet) the only way to remove a mob from a boat.

Comment: ...and yet one can use leashes on all mobs that can be leashed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a lead to make the cow/animal to stand up, but don't walk away because then it will just get back in the boat.  When on the lead, the animal will just kind of stand on top of the boat, then you can destroy the boat with a sword without hurting the animal.

Comment: A combination of the existing answers, but this sounds promising.

Answer (score 0):

If the cow entered there accidentally,remove the boat by hitting it(don't hit the cow!),and don't let it get back in the boat again,if you do not want this trouble again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't hit the boat on the sides or else it hits the animal.

I was transporting my horse and had to get under the boat AND hit the boat in the right spot (seemed to be a bottom corner).

Answer (score 0):

Amazingly I just used a **lead** to remove a dog from a boat. I haven't thoroughly tested this, but you happen to have a lead, use it on the animal (you may or may not need to 'lead it out').

Comment: Just tested this, it works as described. It's also documented on the wiki. https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Boat#Behavior "(…) until the player uses a fishing rod or lead to remove the mob."

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Bob's answer, you can use <kbd>F3</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to view the hitboxes of the boat and the animal, to make sure when breaking the boat you don't accidentally hurt the animal too